# Вопрос по JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Привет. Было задание написать скрипт ,при нажатии на кнопку будет ее просто прятать.

Вот кнопка:

```
<button name="OK" onclick="my_onclick()" id="button_2" >OK</button>
```

Вот функция:

```
  function my_onclick() {
    var element = document.getElementById('button_2');
    element.style.display = "none";
}
```

С javascript столкнулся 1 раз. Функция работает, но я понимаю что она так скажем не универсальна и работает только с button_2. Как надо правильно задать параметр функции `getElementById('')` чтобы работал для всех кнопок с другими ID? Спасибо!

Comment: Можно по "name"

Comment: document.getElementById(name); поменял
но уже не работает... что-то пропустил?

Comment: Как-то так:  

    <button onclick="my_onclick(this)">OK</button>
    <button onclick="my_onclick(this)">OK2</button>

    function my_onclick( target ) {
        target.style.display = "none";
    };

Comment: ReinRaus, СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/PYjhS/

```
<button name="OK" onclick="my_onclick('button_2')" id="button_2" >OK</button>
<button name="OK" onclick="my_onclick('button_3')" id="button_3" >OK</button>

function my_onclick(el) { 
    document.getElementById(el).style.display = "none"; 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за оперативную помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    event.target.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<button>6</button>
<button>7</button>
<button>8</button>
```